How to remove leading white-space in multi-line raw string-literals
When using multi-line raw string literals, how do we tell the compiler not to include the leading spaces?
I have the following bit of code:
#include <string>
#include <print>

int main()
{
   constexpr auto preamble =
      R"(
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
           <meta name="Author" content="Some One" />
           <title>Title Of Page</title>
        </head>
        <body style="">
      )";

   std::println("{}", preamble);

   return 0;
}

The output is as follows:
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
           <meta name="Author" content="Some One" />
           <title>Title Of Page</title>
        </head>
        <body style="">

Which seems to take the leading spaces into account. I'm looking for something like the following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta name="Author" content="Some One" />
   <title>Title Of Page</title>
</head>
<body style="">

I know I can shift the definition all the way to the left, but when the string-literal is within a class method or within nested namespaces, it sort of breaks the indentation of the code.

A raw string literal is always as "raw" as possible in the sense that it will hold exactly the code points present in the source file, with the minor exception that \r and \r\n in the source file are replaced by \n.
If you do want the whitespace in the source, but not the literal, you can't have the literal span the whitespace.
One way to avoid this is to put each line in its own literal, adding the newline manually:
   constexpr auto preamble =
        R"(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>)" "\n"
        R"(<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">)" "\n"
        R"(<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">)" "\n"
        R"(<head>)" "\n"
        R"(   <meta name="Author" content="Some One" />)" "\n"
        R"(   <title>Title Of Page</title>)" "\n"
        R"(</head>)" "\n"
        R"(<body style="">)" "\n"
   ;

Another solution would be to store the string literal with the whitespace into a std::string and then manually remove the whitespace at runtime (or compile-time even if you store the result in a std::array).

ooh yeah, forgot we could simply concat string literals, an excellent and simple solution.

@user17732522 is correct in that literals are supposed to handle some complex parsing and constraints across character codes etc, so you have a few couple options.

If these are fairly global or can be decoupled from the class you can go ahead and include these definitons from a "lookup" file where each entry is left aligned on each new literal. (probably not the best result but if you're OCD on no whitespace yet clear literals, it would work)

Create a literal for each line as suggested by @user17732522 such that there is no whitespace, this is harder to read for maintainability but fixes the issue and keeps the definition in the class.

Build a customer parser to remove the white-space and indent the string specific for your use-case. E.g. HTMLFormatter::FormatString() which would then go through, tokenize each tag and newline each tag with indentations (could be a library you include or write your own).


If I were you I would probably just stick with what you have now. It looks good for code maintainability, has minimal impact on performance or scalability, and unless printing the code to the console is highly important or sending it to a secondary service or to a browser is causing a compatability issue, there is no real need to worry too much about the aditional spacing.

You can take the raw string literal as constexpr input and output a buffer without the leading spaces in a compile-time string.
